# In javafx I have multiple different linecharts and I want to style all of them separately with css

Tags: css, javafx

In JavaFX with css is there a way to individually style different charts without having the css override all of my charts. When I change the css for one chart it overrides the others? How do I make css code for individual charts as opposed to all of them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, set the ID of your charts like

```
...
final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
lineChart.setId("chart1");
...
final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart2 = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
lineChart2.setId("chart2");
...
```

You can then reference each individual chart by its id through the `#id` selector in CSS.

Assumed that you want to display two Line charts with one series each, and you want to show the series in the first chart as black and the series in the second chart as yellow, you can use the following CSS:

```
#chart1 .default-color0.chart-series-line { 
    -fx-stroke: black; 
}

#chart2 .default-color0.chart-series-line { 
    -fx-stroke: yellow; 
}
```

See also [Styling Charts with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks very much, I ended up figuring it out and that's how I did it. Thanks for the help.